# Why am I allowed to pass a function that returns a non-Unit into a method that takes a function that returns a Unit?

Tags: scala

Here is the code:

```
def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet = {
  foreach(tweet =>
    if(p(elem)) acc.incl(elem)
    else acc.incl(elem))
  acc
}

def foreach(f: Tweet => Unit): Unit = {
  f(elem)
  left.foreach(f)
  right.foreach(f)
}

def incl(x: Tweet): TweetSet = {
  if (x.text < elem.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left.incl(x), right)
  else if (elem.text < x.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left, right.incl(x))
  else this
}
```

`foreach` takes `f`, which returns a `Unit`.
`incl` returns a `TweetSet`.
It appears that the function I'm passing in to `filterAcc` returns a `TweetSet`, because the last line in both the if and the else calls `incl`.  Is it the case that even if a value appears as the last line of a function returning a `Unit`, it simply won't return that value?  Sorry if this is an elementary question, I'm a brand new programmer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a special case with `Unit`. If you pass a function `f` (or value) that returns a non-Unit type to another function that expects a `Unit` type, the non-Unit value is discarded in favor of `Unit`.

From the [Scala spec - 6.26.2 Value Conversions](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#value-conversions):

> Value Discarding
>
> If e has some value type and the expected type is Unit, e is converted to the expected type by embedding it in the term { e; () }.

This can be useful in the case where you call a side-effecting function that returns a value that is not `Unit`, but you don't care about that what value is (for whatever reason).

Comment: For the BNP (brand-new programmer), mention `-Ywarn-value-discard` for this dastardly behavior.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up. Thanks for the link too, I'm sure it'll answer many of my future questions.